# DailySalesReportLLSRQ returns TICKETING DATABASE ERROR

Tags: sabre

Request to DailySalesReport service in development enviromant:

```
   <ns6:DailySalesReportRQ Version="2.0.0"
          xmlns:ns1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"
          xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
          xmlns:ns6="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"
          xmlns:ns7="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01"
          xmlns:ns8="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v120" xmlns:ns9="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ns6:SalesReport PseudoCityCode="5VYJ" StartDate="2020-02-13"/>
        </ns6:DailySalesReportRQ>
```

Receive: **ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE** with "**TICKETING DATABASE ERROR**"

What does the TICKET DATABASE ERROR mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all u must check if the date u request have any doc issued.

Below the RAW request for the service="DailySalesReportLLSRQ" which i do now!
POST https://webservices.havail.sabre.com/websvc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "DailySalesReportLLSRQ"
Content-Length: 1503
Host: webservices.havail.sabre.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

Shared/IDL:IceSess/SessMgr:1.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS/RESA!ICESMSLB/RES.LB!-2917635922269276274!1343176!0!1
      
      
         
            soapui.gwaereo@cvccorp.com.br
         
         
            https://webservices.havail.sabre.com/websvc
         
         _
         soapui.gwaereo@cvccorp.com.br
         DailySalesReport
         DailySalesReportLLSRQ
         
            3912336541697520620
            2020-02-21T15:02:49

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.sabre.com/eticketcouponllsrq mentions:

> Common errors
>
> TICKETING DATABASE ERROR:
>
> - The ticket has been issued from PCC XXX and It can be viewed only from this PCC.
> - Please remove the conjunctive ticket number in your request and you should be able to get a good response.
> - Carrier does not seem to have the image of this ticket available.

Seems the service is orchestrated so it is impossible to identify whi PNR / ticket causes a trouble. You need to contact Sabre support and provide a request body + a date of error.